# Why do we believe in symmetry being a unifying principle in elementary particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, models, unified-theories

As far as I can see, symmetry is something that is preferred at lower temperature. For example a crystal lattice has discrete translational symmetries at $T=0$, but at $T>0$ this symmetry is not exact anymore. A rotational machine works fine if it is cooled, but it experiences wear and finally fails, if it gets too hot.

However, unified theories attempt to conjecture a higher symmetry at higher temperatures. I just don't understand why. Of course, I know the difference between an ordinary spatial symmetry and a gauge symmetry, but who can say that gauge symmetries do not follow the same principles.

Naively, I would expect that "unification"/beyond standard model theories are more complicated rather than being simpler, and that what appears as a coupling constant or a discrete charge becomes variable or continuous at higher energy scales.

Is this intuition of mine wrong for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lattice actually is a great example of how you appear to have *less* symmetry at low temperatures, *not more*! And, funnily enough, this works in exactly the same way that that many expect it to work in particle physics!

If you have a gas, the atoms are apparently isotropic. If you move from one place to another, things roughly "look the same." However, if you have a crystal, and move from one place to another, everything looks very different. Say the lattice spacing is $L$. If you move, say, $L/4$ in the crystal, you can tell you've moved $L/4$.

Of course, if you move integer multiples of $L$, you get back to where you started. With the gas, you have a whole $\mathbb{R}$ group of apparent symmetry. Once you have a crystal at low temperatures/energies, you now only have a *subgroup* of that, namely $\mathbb{Z}$! So the crystal symmetry group is actually *smaller* than the gas symmetry group, as $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$!

Now, in reality, there's a difference between what I've called the "apparent symmetry group," seen by a person moving around in the space, and the "actual symmetry group." The actual symmetry group of the lattice is still $\mathbb{R}$. This involves moving the whole lattice around. However, to *physically* move the whole lattice (not just mathematically) would involve an infinite amount of energy (assuming the lattice is infinitely big.)

Now to make the analogy with particle physics,

- Original "$\mathbb{R}$" = highest symmetry group, maybe $SU(5)$ or something like that
- The lattice = "the ground state"
- Smaller $\mathbb{Z}$ subgroup  = unbroken subgroup which appears in the standard model, i.e. $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$.

The highest symmetry group, maybe $SU(5)$ or something, is still a full symmetry of the theory. However, acting a $SU(5)$ transformation on the whole world changes the ground state. Meanwhile, the unbroken $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$ preserves the ground state, and just acts nontrivially on little perturbations of the ground state, i.e. 'particles.'

Comment: That sounds very reasonable and intuitive. Does this lend itself to the assumption that the standard model could possibly be extended on its low-energy end, and the heat death of the universe being something that appears to have a discrete symmetry and the universe ending up as a kind of crystal (once the role of gravitation in the QFT framework is understood)? Or is this too far-fetched?

Answer (score 3):

To be honest I think the idea that "symmetry is a unifying principle" is largely a theoretical prejudice, albeit one made by informed analogies with the history of physics and with other fields like condensed matter.

There are many historical examples of apparently different laws being unified:

- Galileo's observations about falling objects and Kepler's laws of planetary motion were synthesized via Newton's universal law of gravitation.
- The periodic table, revealing that matter is composed of repeated copies of the same basic elements, and that there are regularities in the properties of elements.
- Maxwell's equations unifying apparently different phenomena of electricity, magnetism, and light.
- Special relativity, unifying space and time into a space-time "Poincair{'e}" symmetry.
- General relativity, unifying gravity with special relativity by introducing general coordinate invariance and a lack of prior geometry.
- The electroweak theory, unifying the weak and electromagnetic forces into a $SU(2)$ gauge theory.
- The strong nuclear force, unifying the huge zoo of particles found in the 50s into a simpler structure determined by $SU(3)$ gauge theory (QCD).

And on and on.

There are also many overlaps between particle physics and condensed matter physics. The Higgs mechanism is a nice example. Weinberg has a very nice paper explaining superconductivity as the theory of a spontaneously broken $U(1)$ symmetry. More generally, the Wilsonian renormalization group was very much inspired by condensed matter physics, where one knows the continuum description ultimately breaks down at short distances and is replaced by a lattice. This Wilsonian logic is very much used in particle physics, even though it is much less clear what is going on at high energies (although part of the point is that this shouldn't matter).

**Anyway**, all of this is to say... the history of physics has many examples of the success of searching for new symmetries unifying existing laws. Condensed matter has also exploited this strategy and been successful, and particle physics has learned a lot from condensed matter (and vice versa). So it's very reasonable to hope that this strategy will keep working. But, that is not to say that this is guaranteed to work. Indeed one could argue that the failure to find supersymmetry, or some solution of the hierarchy problem, at the LHC is a sign that there is something not quite right about the way we think about particle physics.

Comment: Your last paragraph is what I have been thinking about the topic. There are so many cases in real life, where people try to compensate ceasing success by "just working harder", it's reasonable (and exemplified!) that it happens in physics as well. But, of course, there is always the question about what to do alternatively.

Comment: @oliver Yes, and there is certainly pressure to publish papers so people need to have something productive to work on. But (in my opinion) no one has a clear idea where the next discovery will really come from in particle physics, or even if it is possible to improve on what we know given tools available to us.

Comment: Interestingly, the biggest steps forward have often required no tremendous experimental effort to trigger them (Faraday->Maxwell, Newton->Einstein,...). At least up until quantum mechanics/quantum field theory. I wonder if the next step couldn't just be a bright idea instead of the next accelerator generation. But I haven't had one, albeit I have tried very hard for many years.

Comment: @oliver This is certainly a popular philosophy, and it may well be that one day a paper appears on arxiv with a revolutionary new way of thinking about physics that reveals the right questions to ask. And it's not enough to say our current theories are successful explaining the experiments we have done to date, since this was also try in 1900 before relativity and quantum mechanics were discovered. But personally I think the challenge we face today is not in coming up with new ideas that could work; but that we lack a useful experimental filter that can tell us which new ideas **don't** work.

Answer (score 2):

Where there is  a symmetry there is a conservation law in quantum mechanics.
Because conservation laws ( charge, momentum, energy) have proved useful in the past
and because, even when they have been broken e.g CP symmetry they have been rescued ( in this case by CPT symmetry),  it seems logical to carry on with them.This of course doesn't mean that conservation (and therefore symmetry) is always true. Nobody knows.

Comment: This is true of *continuous* symmetries. There has been the occasional effort to do something similar with *discrete* symmetries, but controversially so.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental physics is almost the study of symmetries. This is largely due to Noether's Theorem. Because the equations of motion derive from symmetries. So, physics without symmetry is physics without equations of motion. Hence, almost not physics.

Comment: I know that gauge invariant Lagrangians are very successful, just as sex is. And yet there are a huge lot of organisms (at least counted by individuals) that reproduce without sex. What disqualifies non-gauge invariant Lagrangians for example?